# Can you give an example of Metropolis and Metropolis-Hastings algorithm?

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

I have studied many books and tried to understand both the Metropolis and Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Everywhere it is written in the context of the Ising model or Lenard-Jones Energy. I am having difficulty understanding the algorithm from this context.

Can you give an example without using the context of Physics/Mechanics/Dynamics?

A source code example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what books you have read, but I personally enjoyed both the explanatory approaches of Ben Lambert (A Student’s Guide to Bayesian Statistics) and Richard McElreath (Statistical Rethinking A Bayesian Course with Examples in R and STAN). McElreath even provides a source code example of the Metropolis algorithm and HMC in R.

Comment: (+1) Yes, McElreath sets Metropolis Hastings within the Bayesian modelling setting and hence in a much broader setting than Physics. So do [our Monte Carlo books.](https://amzn.to/3xD2mfC)